# Sort image as NP array

Tags: python, numpy, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to sort an image by luminosity using NumPy, which I'm new to. I've managed to create a random image and sort it.

```
def create_image(output, width, height, arr):

  array = np.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)

  numOfSwatches = len(arr)
  swatchWidth = int(width/ numOfSwatches)

  for i in range (0, numOfSwatches):
    m = i * swatchWidth
    r = (i+1) * swatchWidth 
    array[:, m:r] = arr[i]

  img = Image.fromarray(array)
  img.save(output)
```

Which creates this image:
[image: random colour stripes]

So far so good. Only now I want to switch from creating random images to loading them and *then* sorting them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# --------------------------------------------------------------
def load_image( infilename ) :
  img = Image.open( infilename )
  img.load()
  data = np.asarray( img, dtype = "int32" )
  return data

# --------------------------------------------------------------
def lum (r,g,b):
 return math.sqrt( .241 * r + .691 * g + .068 * b )


myImageFile = "random_colours.png"
imageNP = load_image(myImageFile)
imageNP.sort(key=lambda rgb: lum(*rgb) )
```

The image should look like this:
[image: stripe image sorted by luminosity]

The error I get is `TypeError: 'key' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` I may have created the NP array incorrectly as it worked when it was a random NP array.

Answer (score 1):

Have not ever used PIL, but the following approach hopefully works (I'm not sure as I can't reproduce your exact examples), and of course there might be more efficient ways to do so.
I'm using your functions, having changed the `math.sqrt` function to `np.sqrt` in the `lum` function - as it is better for vector calculations. By the way, I believe this won't work with an `int32` type array (as in your `load_image` function).

The key part is Numpy's [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy-argsort) function (last line), which gives the indices that would sort the given array; this is applied to a row of the luminosity array (exploiting simmetry) and later used as indexer of `img_array`.

```
# Create random image
np.random.seed(4)
img = create_image('test.png', 75, 75, np.random.random((25,3))*255)
# Convert to Numpy array and calculate luminosity
img_array  = np.array(img, dtype = np.uint8)
luminosity = lum(img_array[...,0], img_array[...,1], img_array[...,2])
# Sort by luminosity and convert to image again
img_sorted = Image.fromarray(img_array[:,luminosity[0].argsort()])
```

The original picture:
[image: The original picture]

And the luminosity-sorted one:
[image: And the luminosity-sorted one]

Comment: Now it’s more clear !! Wasn’t able to guess arr from the first post (that misses import math too)

Comment: ''....having changed the math.sqrt function to np.sqrt in the lum function - as it is better for vector calculations. ....'' I would say not better but the only way to make it work !! As math.sqrt gives :    return math.sqrt( .241 * r + .691 * g + .068 * b )

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @pippo1980, Ah yes, I wasn't sure about it, but it only works on scalars.

Comment: yep now I need to figure out what a scalar is :-)

Comment: what about lum(img_array[...,0] ....    meaning the three dots [...,0] ? not sure about what they represent in python ?   I would have guessed something like :,:,0  ?

Comment: @pippo1980, in Numpy, `...` is to take all the elements of the axes not numerically defined, e.g., `[:,:,:,0]` is equivalent to `[...,0]`, as you guessed.